# Diferença de gulp parallel e gulp series

Tags: javascript, gulp

Qual a diferença de usar um ou outro no gulp v4?

Antes eu fazia algo como `gulp.task('default', ['build']);`

Mas agora da erro...

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`series()` combina tarefas e as executa uma depois da outra, na ordem especificada. Exemplo:

```
const { series } = require('gulp');

function cleanDist(cb) {
  // task code...
}

function buildHTML(cb) {
  // task code...
}

exports.build = series(cleanDist, buildHTML);
```

Essa sintaxe usando `exports` faz parte da recomendação da v4 do Gulp.

O `parallel` serve para executar diferentes tarefas simultaneamente: recomendável para tarefas que não dependem uma das outras.

Exemplo:

```
const { parallel } = require('gulp');

function buildCSS(cb) {
  // task code...
}

function buildHTML(cb) {
  // task code...
}

exports.build = parallel(buildCSS, buildHTML);
```

Você também pode criar tarefas compostas (coloquei em uma variável só como exemplo, poderia chamar no exports diretamente):

```
const { parallel, series } = require('gulp');

// funções ...

const buildProcess = series(cleanDist, parallel(buildCSS, buildHTML));
exports.default = buildProcess;
```

Recomendo a leitura da [documentação](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start).

**Sobre o erro** que obteve, você pode substituir pela sintaxe dos exemplo que mostrei, ou então, fazer da seguinte forma:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.{series|parallel});
```

O seguinte post também pode te ajudar: https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/